# Button style in HTML,CSS,Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have set a background  .jpg image in HTML page. on top of the .jpg image I have placed a About us button. I want to style the button as in the below site

http://www.wix.com/sample/website-viewer?lng=en&site_id=1379243637074592

please help on this

My HTML file is:-

```
<div class="feature_home" style="background-image: url('img/main.jpg');">
        <p class="feature_text">I really appreciate your guys help!</p>
        <a class="feature_button" href="/xyz-101/">About us</a>
    </div>
```

My CSS file is

```
.feature_home{
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0; 
    left: 0; 
    right: 0; 
    bottom: 0; 
    margin: auto; 
    min-width: 50%;
    min-height: 50%;
}
.feature_text{
    position:absolute;
    right:2px;
    bottom:15px;
}
.feature_button{
    right:2px;
    bottom:2px;
    position:absolute;
}`
```

TIA

Answer (score 0):

You can ameliorate this project to get what you want: http://cssdeck.com/labs/css-only-showhide